# Javascript Generated Select Drop-down Menu From Url=NULL HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

The Website Have a Normal HTML Menu

assume in format

```
<ul> 
   <li><a>
      <ul> 
         <li><a href=""></li>
         <li><a href=""></li>
         <li><a href=""></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When Below xx Screen Size Javascript Triggers and Removes this nav

Creates new Select dropdown in format

```
<select>
   <option val="undefine">text value</option>
   <option val="url">text value</option>
   <option val="url">text value</option>
   <option val="url">text value</option>
</select>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to disable click for Option that is not going to have a URL value?

Comment: Add a class `.noclick` to the option, and then disable the option with `attr()` like `<option class="noclick" value="undefined" disabled>text value</option>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to select the elements which do not have the value `"url"` in the attr named `val`, then a simple selector such as `$('select option[val!="url"]')` would work.

If you need to check if the value of attr `val` is a URL, then you will need to do some more work.

I would just select all `<option>` elements, then use jquery .grep to filter the array based on the value of the `val` attribute. Use a function such as this http://dzone.com/snippets/validate-url-regexp to determine if the value of val is a URL or not. Then once you have an array of all `<option>` elements whose `val` attribute does not contain a URL, add the `disabled` attribute to each element.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option